# CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda envs'. Did you mean 'conda env'?

Tags: python, anaconda, environment-variables, conda

As of conda 4.10.1, here is what worked for me using the Git Bash terminal in Sublime text 3 (same for cmd and Git cmd) on Windows:

Note that I installed two version of python , the original python (3.8.6) and the Anaconda version (with python 3.8.8), and both version are added to my path:

> C:\Users\sohaib\anaconda3

> C:\Users\sohaib\anaconda3\Scripts

> C:\Users\sohaib\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts\

when I try to execute this command `conda --info envs` I get this error

> CommandNotFoundError: No command 'conda envs'.
> Did you mean 'conda env'?

but this command `conda env list` work good and display conda environments normally

how to fix this problem?

Comment: is it a typo that you are using envs instead of env ?

Comment: @ abhishek phukan , no typo

Comment: There is no `conda envs` subcommand; at least with conda 4.3.30. The usual way to list the available conda environments is `conda info -e`.

Comment: @Kurtis Rader yes its my fault I m sorry,, there isn't [conda --info envs] , the commad is [conda info --envs]

Comment: @karbi You should close your question since it has been resolved.